# Minimum between consecutive values

Tags: r, minimum

I am looking for a function similar to `diff` but instead of calculating the difference between two consecutive values, I want to compute the minimum between them. That is, If y have `x <- c(7,3,17,9)` what I want is `c(3,3,9)` as an output.
Is it there an implemented function to make this (not only for the minimum but also for maximum or other functions?

**Explanation**:

The first value (3) is the minimum between the first two elements `min(c(7,3))`

The second value (3) is the minimum between the second and third elements 
`min(c(3,17))`

The third value (9) is the minimum between the third and fourth elements `min(c(17,9))`

Comment: I didn't get how you got `c(1, 1, 9)`. Maybe explain a bit more.

Comment: You can look into `rollmax`, `rollmean` from **zoo** package. But these are generally for timeseries data. Also, you can check out the **fMultivar** package.

Comment: Thank you @TUSH, the solution was `rollapply(c(7,3,17,9),2,min)`. The `rollapply()`function was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pmin()` to calculate the minimum between each element of two or more vectors. Use `head()` and `tail()` to create a pair of right-sized and offset vectors.

```
> x = c(7,3,17,9)
> pmin(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
[1] 3 3 9
```

Two advantages over `rollapply()` are that it does not require additional packages, and that the same syntax works when the vector is of length 0 and so is more robust in scripts or functions that you might hope to reuse.

```
> x = numeric(); pmin(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
numeric(0)
> x = numeric(); rollapply(x, 2, min)
Error in max(sapply(dat, length)) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this alternative and the explanation of why it is better to use it.

Comment: The development version of zoo handles that edge case and is more readable.  To install: `install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`